# laravel yajra datatable how to display json data in datatable column

Tags: laravel, yajra-datatable

i have a member table that has 'poin' column with json data,
example:

{"IDR":"100", "MYR":"50", "DOLLAR":"25"}

how can i display that json data in one cell table using datatable?

```
Name  | Poin       |
____________________
User 1|IDR : 100   |
      |MYR : 50    |
      |DOLLAR : 25 |
____________________
User 2|IDR : 50    |
      |MYR : 80    |
      |DOLLAR : 125|
```

this is the controller

```
public function query(Request $request)
{
    $query = DB::table('members');

    $result = DataTables::of($query)->make(true);

    return $result;
}
```

here's the blade.php

```
 var oTable = $('#datatable-responsive').DataTable({
            autoWidth: false,
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            responsive: true,
            ajax: {
                url: "{{route('members.query')}}",
                method: "POST",
                data: function (d) {
                    d.search = $('input[type="search"]').val();
                }
            },
            columns: [
                {data: "name"},
                {data: "poin"},
                {data: "created_at"}
            ]
        });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Firstly consider casting the JSON field in your Member model to an array:

```
class Member extends Model
{
    protected $casts = [
        'poin' => 'array',
    ];
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting

You could then write a transformer for your Model to be used when you create your Datatable to output the JSON field `poin` as HTML:

```
namespace App\Transformers\Datatables;

use League\Fractal;
use App\Models\Member;

class MemberTransformer extends Fractal\TransformerAbstract
{
    public function transform(Member $member)
    {
        return [
            'id'   => $member->id,
            'name' => $member->name,
            'poin' => "IDR: {$member->poin['IDR']} <br> MYR: {$member->poin['MYR']} <br> DOLLAR: {$member->poin['DOLLAR']}"
        ];
    }

}
```

https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/response/fractal

Then apply the transformer...

```
public function query(Request $request)
{
    $model = Member::query();

    $result = DataTables::of($model)
        ->setTransformer('App\Transformers\Datatables\MemberTransformer')
        ->toJson();

    return $result;
}
```

https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/engine/eloquent

You may need to read the docs and tinker with this code a little as I haven't tested it out, it's just to guide you to experiment with the idea of transformers.